# angular2 child router resolve blocked parent ui render

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

As my case, I rendered `google map` and others components.I want the child render after the `google map` rendered.And I add a `router resolve` to the child route,But the `resolve` blocked, and `google map` is not render.

The structure as follow:

```
//main
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

//child
<div>
   <google-map></google-map>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet> //add resolve here
</div>
```

The structure in  browser as:

[image]

Hope to get the right way to blocked child route. Thanks.

Comment: Share your routing

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I'm not resolve this. any idea?